# Audio is not coming properly in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, audio, sip

I am developing a SIP based application to make and receive a calls. Recently i have tested the application on different devices. first, i have tested with Samsung Galaxy five(2.2) and Samsung Galaxy y(2.3.6),when called both side audio was fine.

But when i have tried with Galaxy y(2.3.6) and Sony XPERIA (4.0.3),there was an one sided voice.Application worked fine with 2.2 and 2.3.6 but while testing with 2.3.6 and 4.0.3 there was an audio issue with ICS.

Anyone have idea about this issue or Had this kind of problem then please give me the some idea about this.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I am using codecs in application and i have created the .so file for that codecs. But i have created the .so file for only **armeabi** processor. And i think in Android 4.0.3 there is an armeabi-v7a. so should i need to create the .so file for armeabi-v7a CPU?

Comment: Which XPeria? There are several different models (Arc, S, P, U, ...).

Comment: its XPeria Arc ! But i don't think there is a problem with particular device.

Comment: Check the logcat output on the XPERIA device, if you haven't yet.

Comment: @lain how to check logcat on the XPERIA device? did you mean in eclipse?

Comment: Where you check the logcat output is your choice ;) On device with an app, with adt-plugin in eclipse or adb logcat on device.

Answer (score 0):

**armeabi** also runs on **armeabi-v7a**.
Anyways, the processor type is device dependent and not OS dependent.
You can Have armeabi-v7 even in Gingerbread...

You need to find the exact position of the package/audio-loss.
In SIP-Applications, the error-chain is quite long.
Can you verify with shark if RTP packets are received on both devices even if you got no audio (You need root for running shark/tcpdump om your device)?
Otherwise, try forcing RTp proxy and run wireshark on the proxy.

If packets are transmitted in both directions, check where the packets are lost and they reach the encoder.
Put logs and checks verywhere in the audio-transmission pipeline until you know where they are gone and feed us with more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification about processors.i will try with shark and let you inform about if i get anything.

Answer (score 0):

as sebweisgerber states, there are several possible failure points, if the call is properly established but no audio is hear, it should be in audio capturing/playing, audio de/codification or audio transmission. If we take into account that this works in 2.3.6 but not 4.0.3, I would bet for audio capturing/playing or codification.

Are you working with third party libraries for codification? Because, if this libraries are trying to access system's codification libraries, like [csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) project, most of library names for decoding have changed from Gingerbread to ICS so, this would explain the "one sided" behaviour.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yeah i am using third party libraries which is MjSip,i used the source of Sipdroid.